# Why can't my Chromium display Japanese characters?

Tags: fonts, chromium, fedora-13

I use Chromium, but it can't display Japanese characters, as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Left is firefox, as you can see, it displayes the characters correctly. Chromium is on the right.

This is Fedora 13, with all browsers and fonts installed from Repositories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a known problem - [Issue 7160: Wrong font for Japanese characters in English language Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7160), dating from January 2008 but unfixed until today.

Only workarounds contributed by users are available, none of which is perfect and some contradict each other.
It seems that the only real solution *at the moment* is to keep on using Firefox.

**Workaround 1** : [Issue 7160: Wrong font for Japanese characters in English language Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7160)

> In the font and language settings, set
>   Serif Font to MS PMincho; Sans-Serif
>   Font to Meiryo; Fixed-Width Font to MS
>   Gothic.
>
> This yields the correct glyphs for all
>   Japanese sites. English looks as usual
>   in  Sans-Serif (most of the Web), but
>   a bit harder to read in Fixed-Width
>   and Serif.

**Workaround 2** : [Chromium and font](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=740384)

> Since I'm in Japan (but I would rather
>   use English), google defaults to the
>   japanese site. On this, all the text
>   becomes squares. However, I installed
>   [Droid font from AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=22528). It comes
>   with Japanese font, and that fixed it.
>   Now when I go to google, I can
>   actually read the Japanese webpage

**Workaround 3** : [How to display Japanese characters in Google Chrome/Chromium?](http://allaboutfedora.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-display-japanese-characters-in.html)

remove google-droid fonts:

```
yum remove google-droid*
```

Answer (score 7):

For Japanese characters:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-sazanami-gothic
```

For Chinese characters:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-arphic-uming ttf-arphic-zenhei
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-arphic-uming ttf-arphic-ukai
```

For Korean characters:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-unfonts-core
```

Comment: Yeah, well, ok, but Fedora is RPM based. No `apt-get` just like that, etc...

Comment: r/apt-get /rpm --/

Answer (score 2):

For 2021 and later on Debian:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt search mincho
```

[image: sudo apt search mincho]

There should be many Japanese fonts now. I recommend the Takao pack, but please choose a package from those available at the time you read this.

```
sudo apt install fonts-takao
```

You do not need to log out and back in again, but you **must** completely close and reopen Chrome for the fonts to be picked up.

[image: Restart Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it appears that the sazanami font packages will provide the support needed. On Fedora 29 the proper fonts can be installed using this command:

```
dnf install sazanami-mincho-fonts sazanami-gothic-fonts sazanami-fonts-common
```